# ATMEGA168 Pin Mappings

Tags: atmega

Where can I find pin mappings for the ATMEGA168?

Comment: -1. This is one of the worst questions I've seen here so far. If you plan to use a microcontroller I presume you must have heard of datasheets.

Answer (score 10):

Page 2 of the ATMega168 data sheet has the pin mappings for all four packages of the chip, and pages 3 and 4 give a bit more information regarding some of the basic pin functions:

http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc2545.pdf

Comment: You have just RTFM ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Of course this can be found in the atmega168 datasheet from Atmel but sometimes it is also handy to know which Arduino pins correspond to the Atmega168 pin numbers. This reference can be found on the [Arduino site](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping).

Answer (score 4):

You can either go to [the manufacturers website](http://www.atmel.com) directly and search for your device ([ATMega168 is here](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/Product_card.asp?part_id=3303), with link to the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc2545.pdf))).

Another very good resource for everything AVR is the [AVR Freaks](http://www.avrfreaks.net/) community. <strike>They have a [Device list](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?module=Freaks%20Devices&func=viewDev)</strike> (Gone, use Atmel's [here](http://atmel.com/dyn/products/param_table.asp?category_id=163&family_id=607&subfamily_id=760)) (ATMega168 is [here](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?module=Freaks%20Devices&func=displayDev&objectid=78)) where you can get a quick overview of the chips features, the pin mappings, and of course the official data sheet, too.

Personally, I prefer AVR Freaks for my projects. Ironically, the default search on Atmel.com is google-wide - and directly links to AVR Freaks, too.

Comment: We didn't allow links to be inserted by new users to prevent spam.  The links you posted were very good, though!  Here's an upvote to help you gain more privileges and continue contributing.

Comment: Thanks very much. Unfortunately though AVR Freaks discontinued the device list (or at least searching for it), leading to Atmel.com which search and comparison featuers are really lacking. Personally, I doubt the smartness of this decision from Atmel Corp.

Comment: Thanks for the update on the broken link.  I've fixed your answer for now, you can edit it with new information in the future with the "Edit" link.

Comment: (Note that the `strike` tags are just because I agree that AVR Freaks' removal of the device list is ill advised, and the links to the individual micros are still working so I think they might bring it back - you are free to remove obsolete information entirely if you like.)

Answer (score 3):

Be aware, shameless promotion ;)

Here is a cheat sheet with the ATmega-Arduino pin mapping on it.
http://tinkerlog.com/2009/06/18/microcontroller-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 2):

You may find it at http://www.msarnoff.org/chipdb/atmega168. Very plain and simple site. They will also link you to the original ATMega PDF document if you need more than just a pinout.